# Import a war in IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, war

I have worked on eclipse before and new to IntelliJ.

I have a war with me(its an example from apache). I want to import it to intellij. but it seems that IDEA does not support importing. I also have unpackaged version of the war file.

How can I import or do equivalent in Intellij and get all the contents?

Comment: what are you trying to do by "importing" a war? A war is file that is deployed in a webserver; I do not understand what you want to do with it in IntelliJ

Comment: A war file doesn't contain any source code. What would be the point of "importing it" in IntelliJ. You don't need an IDE to deploy a war file.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that  *war also contain the source java Code*, "myclass.java" here is the answer :

There isn't a direct way I know about :

1. first open WinRAR
2. drag the war file into WinRAR
3. extract content
4. copy the HTML, JSP, etc. files and css, javaScript folder to the "web folder in your project" (you should create new one before starting).
5. navigate to class folder deleted all .class file keep only .java files 
   take all folder copy to " src folder in your project "
6. the import thing don't forget to copy  the deployment descriptor "web.xml"

finally rebuild the project